# Fill the Gaps between buttons in LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, layout

I have a `LinearLayout` and two buttons inside arranged horizontally.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.tryingstuffs.MainActivity" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="2"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I google a lot but i haven`t found solution for my problem: In between the buttons - there is space a little bit. How can i delete the space and make the buttons position right after each other?
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771299/buttons-spacing/13772037

Comment: Use a hierarchyviewer tool to see if there are spaces in LinearLayout or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using weights in layout make sure you put corresponding height or width length to be zero, which in your case is width, put your width zero, :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.tryingstuffs.MainActivity" >
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"  
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:text="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:text="2"
        />
   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit**

I am sorry, I have edited my answer, the thing is if you add a background to button, then you won't see the gap, try doing the way I have edited above.

Hope this helps...